# javascript user click

Tags: javascript

I want to record the element (element id or xpath) that the user clicks on, for example if its a href it records the xpath or id or text. How can I do this with javascript?

What i have:
click:

```
function recordClick() {
        var a = document.location
        alert("you just clicked on the page"+ a);
}

function onPageLoad() {
    //document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = recordClick;
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].onclick = recordClick;
}

window.onload = onPageLoad;
```

xpath:

```
function createXPathFromElement(elm) { 
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for (segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
    { 
        if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                    if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                    if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                }; 
                if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                    segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                    return segs.join('/'); 
                } else { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                } 
        } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
        } else { 
            for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++; }; 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
        }; 
    }; 
    return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
}; 

function lookupElementByXPath(path) { 
    var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(); 
    var result = evaluator.evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
    return  result.singleNodeValue; 
}
```

Comment: state the issue you are having with your current code.

Comment: I do not know how to combine the two, to make a script record the xpath or referecne or etc on the element that was clicked on by the user

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen for the click event like this

```
$(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
       // do whatever you want to with the captured event
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Did I miss the jQuery tag here? Please, don't assume jQuery. The OP isn't using it anywhere in the question, and there is no jQ tag. Not everybody uses it

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get the id of something clicked with

```
document.body.onclick = function(anEvent) {
    console.log(anEvent.target.id)
};
```

If you're using jQuery you can get a ton of information about the object clicked

```
$("body").click(function(anEvent){ console.log(anEvent);});
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better of trying `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` in IE < 9):

```
var processClick = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    switch(target.tagName.toLowerCase())
    {
        case 'a':
            //do something with target.href || target.getAttribute('href');
            return e;//<-- perhaps .preventDefault() && .stopPropagation()
        case 'img': //deal with distict tags the way you want
            return img.getAttribute('src');//<-- do whatever you need to do here
    }
    if (target.id)
    {
        //do something with target.id
    }
}
if (window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener('click',processClick,false);
}
else
{
    window.attachEvent('onclick',processClick);
}
```

Of course, you can *easily* replace the switch with various function calls, on each occasion passing the element and or the event object as an argument. 
On the XPath thing, you can find some code that might do just that [here, on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath), I think the `getXPathForElement` there might suit your needs particularly well.